# Oracle traverse tree upto specific node

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

How to traverse tree from some child nodes up to specific node in Oracle (not to root node)?

We have input: a specific node A, a list child nodes.

Output expected: subtree from node A to all the child node of A in the input list.

We have write some query, but wonder if we could have a better way to do that.

Thank for any help!

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT '1' AS code, ' ' AS code_ct FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', ' ' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '11', '1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '12', '1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '111', '11' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '112', '11' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1111', '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1112', '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1113', '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1114', '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1115', '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '21', '2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '211', '21' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '22', '2' FROM dual 
)
--Current query that give expected output
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
START WITH code IN ('1112', '1114', '1115', '211')
CONNECT BY PRIOR code_ct = code
INTERSECT 
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
START WITH code = '11'
CONNECT BY PRIOR code = code_ct;
/*
--test improving query 
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(code , '_'), 2)  AS path
FROM table_name
WHERE code = '11'
START WITH code IN ('1112', '1114', '1115', '221')
CONNECT BY PRIOR code_ct = code;
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM table_name
START WITH code IN ('1112', '1114', '1115', '221')
CONNECT BY PRIOR code_ct = code and prior code <> '11'
order by 1;
```

Since INTERSECT operator removes duplicates from the final resultset, then DISTINCT must be used in order to get the same result as from the query with intersect.

Comment: Ar, sorry but this get the wrong result with the code '211', I have update the question for that case.